# How to maximally crop a rotated image?

Tags: image-processing

I'm cropping a rotated image, but I want to keep the ascect ratio fixed and not have any "extra" black pixels. Here's an example:

```
image = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}];
rot = ImageRotate[image, 5 Degree]
ImageCrop[rot, {250, 200}]
```

[image]

But this isn't a good solution because it specifies the exact crop and I'm *not sure what that will be generally*. So really, what I want is the take a big of a crop as possible, preserving some given aspect ratio (which by default would be the same as the original image's asepect).

I would manually do it like this:

[image]

**Details**

- Please assume we know the exact angle of rotation and have the original unrotated image.
- Related:

  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789239/calculate-largest-rectangle-in-a-rotated-rectangle
  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702966/rotate-image-and-crop-out-black-borders/16778797#16778797

Comment: How do you feel about computing it from the morphological components? How fast does this need to be? One other option is to first pad with a very specific random color then find the bounding pixels with that color from the image data.

Comment: @b3m2a1 We should be able to compute it with basic geometry no?

Comment: Oh if you know the rotation angle, sure. Take the corner points of a rectangle, rotate those, take the second from smallest left, second from largest right, or something. I was assuming you had randomly rotated images.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I don't think its that easy. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702966/rotate-image-and-crop-out-black-borders/16778797#16778797

Comment: Oh I missed the `AspectRatio` restriction. I see the complication now.

Comment: @andre yeah I just saw that. I think that's what M.R. wants.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use the option "SameRatioCropping" in `ImageRotate` :

```
image = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}];
ImageRotate[image, 5 Degree,"SameRatioCropping"]
```

[image]

"SameRatioCropping" is documented. There is also a good explanation in [this Almsick's presentation, at time 10 minutes](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?sx=complis&v=1225)